# Convert Java Object with single variable to XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Let's say I have class Foo

```
@XmlRootElement(name="foo")
public class Foo {
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private Bar variable;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
}
```

and class Bar

```
public class Bar {
    @XmlElement
    private String id;
}
```

and I want to get an XML file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<foo>
    <id>bar</id>
    <name>foo</name>
</foo>
```

but instead I get when I run the marshal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<foo>
    <id>    
        <id>bar</id>
    </id>
    <name>foo</name>
</foo>
```

I can't use getters or setters due to having to follow strict encapsulation rules and I can't simply delete the Bar class because the Bar clase holds important business logic in it's constructor.

I know I can use a private getter to do that but it seems like a weird hack and I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution using tags.

I have tried to look into how Jaxb converts String objects to a simple XML string element without success, but I think it was probably hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the previous answer here I managed to find a way to do this.

Class foo doesn't change, it stays as intended

Class bar however, stops using `@XmlElement` and starts using `@XmlValue`, so it would look like this:

```
public class Bar {
    @XmlValue
    private String id;
}
```